# Malformed content in certificate data format .p7b

Tags: c#

I am trying to sign PDFs digitaly but I am getting an error `Malformed Content`.
This happens when I use the class `CmsSignedData` and I pass in the constructor a `FileStream` of the file `certificate.p7b`.

Here is the piece of code where that happens:

```
public void Sign()
        {
            CmsSignedData certificateStore = new CmsSignedData(CertificateChain);
            IX509Store x509Certs = certificateStore.GetCertificates("Collection");
            ArrayList certificateArray = new ArrayList(x509Certs.GetMatches(null));

            List<X509Certificate> certificates = new List<X509Certificate>();
            foreach (var certificate in certificateArray)
            {
                certificates.Add((X509Certificate)certificate);
            }

            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(SourcePlainPdf);

            StampingProperties stampingProperties = new StampingProperties();
            stampingProperties.UseAppendMode();

            PdfSigner pdfSigner = new PdfSigner(pdfReader, 
                new FileStream(DestinationSignedPdf, FileMode.OpenOrCreate), stampingProperties);

            pdfSigner.GetSignatureAppearance().SetPageNumber(1).SetReason(Reason).SetLocation(Location);
            pdfSigner.SetFieldName(SignatureFieldName);

            IExternalSignature pks = new ServerSignature(SourcePlainPdf, AuthenticationToken, 
                QscdServerBaseAddress, CertificateAlias, Seed, Secret, HashAlgorithmOID);
           
           
            pdfSigner.SignDetached(pks, certificates.ToArray(), null, null, null, 0, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);
           
        }
```

The first line of the method: `CmsSignedData certificateStore = new CmsSignedData(CertificateChain);` is where the error happens.
I downloaded the certificates file from the website and stored it in the C: drive.

I've checked another posts for the solution but none spoke directly towards my problem.
A very extensive post dug very deep into cryptography and I couldn't understand a thing.
I am using BouncyCastle for the certificates API.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Finaly I solved the problem.
When I downloaded the certificates .p7b file it gave me two files. I was streaming the wrong one.